# Get LDAP contacts from two different branches

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I need to construct an LDAP search query to get contacts from two different branches,

The first branch is:

**Base dir:** CN=Users,dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com

**filter:** cn=*

The second branch is:

**base dir:** OU=People,OU=eProfile,dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com

**filter:** cn=*

Each search query on its own works fine, however, I am not able to construct one search query that would retrieve users from both branches.

I tried the following and it didn't work:

**base dir:** dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com

**filter:** |((cn=*,CN=Users)(cn=*,OU=People,OU=eProfile))

**base dir:** dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com

**filter:** (|(CN=*,CN=Users,DC=core,DC=dir,DC=mycompany,DC=com)(cn=*,OU=People,OU=eProfile,dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com))

I also tried the extensible search using a filter like "(ou:dn:=People)" but that filter did not return the users under 'People', it only returned 'People' folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since both branches share a common prefix, a Subtree request at the common parent should return entries from both branches. However, you might then want to make sure that only users are returned, and this can be achieved by mentioning the objectClass (person or inetOrgPerson).

```
base dir: dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com
filter: (&(objectclass=person)(cn=*))
```

Comment: I am concerned about the "CN=Users" and "OU=People,OU=eProfile" parts because these are the ones that I am not able to retrieve. Both of them are on the share base dir but no matter what filter I use, I can only retrieve one of them at a single time. Using the filter "(&(objectclass=person)(cn=*))" did not retrieve them specifically but retrieves all users in the shared common prefix "dc=core,dc=dir,dc=mycompany,dc=com"

Comment: For me, it seems that things only work when I put "OU=People,OU=eProfile" as part of the base dir and not the filter. But if I did this, the other branch "CN=Users" will not be retrieved. My current state is: I am able to retrieve only one path at a time, but, I am not able to retrieve both on a single query

Comment: I tried with objectcategory and objectclass without the OU part, they narrowed the retrieved list significantly but it still retrieves other branches that I don't need

Comment: It was not clear from your explanations that you also want to read the containers.

Comment: It was not clear from your explanations that you also want to read the container  entries, nor which entries you are expecting back or excluded. If you want all entries, then (objectclass=*) will return them all.

Comment: In the filter, could you restrict to one branch or another?

Comment: You would restrict to one branch or another by issuing a search with the Branch as the base.